# htaccess check for one place then another after rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After fiddling around with htaccess for hours upon hours I can't seem to get this just right.

What I need to do is when I try and grab an image (say example.jpg) from /images/, it should firstly be redirected to images/e/example.jpg and if it is not found there it should be redirected back to images/example.jpg.
What's strange is I can manage the other way round (i.e check for it in images/example.jpg first then go to images/e/example.jpg)

I would imagine it would be something like this:

```
#This redirects to images/{first letter}/image.jpg
RewriteRule ^images/([^/])([^/]*)$ /images/$1/$1$2 [L]

#Checks to see if it exists, if not redirect it back to the original request
RewriteCond images/e/example.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1 [L]
```

Obviously the rewrite condition should be dynamic for the first letter of the file but I don't know how to do that.

Any help is kindly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/$1/$1$2 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/(\w)([^/]+?\.jpe?g)$ /images/$1/$1$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. Sadly this doesn't seem to work. It doesn't ever pass the conditions. Also I need it to check in /e/ first, then go to /images/ when it doesn't find it in /e/. Is this possible?

Note that it redirects to a folder with the same name as the first letter of the image. I chose /e/ because example.jpg starts with an e. Tesimg.jpg would be in /images/t/

'RewriteRule ^images/([^/])([^/]*)$ /images/$1/$1$2 [L]' works for this.

Comment: So is your request always starting with /images/ like `/images/Tesimg.jpg` ?

Comment: Yes, my request is images/testimg.jpg. Surely I could do it if I had a condition to check if the image exists in images/{first letter}/ then if that's true rewrite it. The only problem is how to write the condition.

Also no, that doesn't work unfortunately. Thanks for the help really appreciate it :)